# JMS Vs JAX-WS or JAX-RS

Tags: soap, jms, jax-ws

I want to understand the usage of these two JAVA EE API's.
I understand that we can use JMS for messaging between two systems/modules, synchronously or asynchronously. We can do this either by P2P or Publish/Subscribe methods.
And I also understand that JAX-WS is the SOAP Implementation Java API.
But in common both offers sending messages and receiving messages.

So my questions are:

1. When should we use JMS over JAX-WS?
2. When should we use JAX-ws over JMS?
3. Is JMS really interoperable?

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad, and possibly opinion based.